# How to align mat-list-item to horizontal without changing its base module css?

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I have a `mat-list` in which I'm iterating my data and displaying my requirement is to align the list in horizontal fashion. This can be easily achieved by using simple `<ul>` but I'm using material and want to utilize the `mat-list` feature of it.
Since material controls come with their on CSS and if we want to change the existing look n feel we need to change it in the base css file.
I don't want to change the main `mat-list-item` css file since it is being many places in the project.
I just want to align the `mat-list-item` horizontal.

```
<mat-list>
  <mat-list-item *ngFor="let privlege of userprivilege"> {{privlege}} </mat-list-item>
</mat-list>




 .mat-list-item {
 float: right;
 display: list-item;
 }
```

I'm new to angular material if anyone can suggest a good way to achieve it would be appreciative.
I did not find the way to do it any where else.

Comment: you should add display:inline-block;

Comment: @Ranjithv it doesn't make any difference

Comment: can you show me the output for this code? I will check and let you know @Karthik Saxena

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add the class like `inline-list` to `mat-list` then change it to `flex` and use that class where ever you want inline list.

> It wont effect other list

*Example*

```
<mat-list class="inline-list">
 <mat-list-item> Pepper </mat-list-item>
 <mat-list-item> Salt </mat-list-item>
 <mat-list-item> Paprika </mat-list-item>
</mat-list>


.mat-list-base.inline-list {
    display: flex;
}
```

> Don't use `float` when you have `flex`

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-8">
          <div>
            <mat-card>
              <mat-card-header>
                 <mat-card-title>Role Privilege</mat-card-title>
              </mat-card-header>
              <mat-card-content>
                 <mat-list class="inline-list">
                    <mat-list-item *ngFor="let privlege of userprivilege"> {{privlege}} </mat-list-item>
                  </mat-list>
               </mat-card-content>
             </mat-card>
         </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, this worked. but the problem now is actually I have a mat-card in which I'm displaying this mat-list. So now the content is going away from the mat-card how to wrap the content means the list within the card

Comment: Can you show me your `mat-list` along with `card` means your html.you can edit in my answer

Comment: I have test that inside ` mat-card`  and its worked well [screenshot](https://www.screencast.com/t/umgL0nJ6hu0g),  try setting these properties to list `display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-flow: row;` may be that worked or share your complete code on stack-blitz

Comment: Works like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

Well if you don't want edit the main CSS, which is never a good idea. You can write your own CSS class for this particular scenario. It will not effect the overall layout but only the list items where you are using it.

```
.horizontal-mat-list-item {
 float: right;
 display: list-item;
 }
```

Have a look at this stack blitz link.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-list-horizontal

Comment: I think its a nice way to do it. But I don't have the permission to install fxlayout.

Comment: You can do it without the fxlayout. I have updated the link please check again :)